# i need help about imap_search multiple filters in php

Tags: php, email, imap

I am seeking for imap_search function filters in php for "FROM" field, can anyone help plz, how can i add multiple domains in "FROM" field. i tried using multiple "FROM" and also tried using separating the domains with delimiter " " and "," but neither worked.

i tried like FROM "mysite.com yoursite.com", i also tried FROM "mysite.com, yoursite.com", even tried FROM "mysite.com" FROM "yoursite.com" but neither of them worked...

hoping for faster responses. thanks for reading out...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but IMAP search syntax has 'or' operator:

```
UID SEARCH OR FROM gmail.com FROM lesnikowski.com
```